# Unity3D - Error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code is listed here, this is coding for an RPG game, however that should not matter when comes to helping me fix this. This is the only problem that the console keeps giving me:

> Assets/Standard Assets/Scripts/Base Player/BasePlayer.cs(20,21): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BasePlayer {

    private string playerName;
    private int playerLevel;
    private BaseCharacterClass playerClass;
    private int speed;
    private int endurance;
    private int strength;
    private int health;

    public string PlayerName{
        get{return playerName;}
        set{playerName = value;}
    }
    public int PlayerLevel{
        get{return playerLevel;}
        set{playerName = value;}
    }
    public BaseCharacterClass PlayerClass{
        get{return playerClass;}
        set{playerClass = value;}
    }
    public int Speed{
        get{return speed;}
        set{speed = value;}
    }
    public int Endurance{
        get{return endurance;}
        set{endurance = value;}
    }
    public int Strength{
        get{return strength;}
        set{strength = value;}
    }
    public int Health{
        get{return health;}
        set{health = value;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing the type definition for "value"?

Comment: Sorry? I am a bit new to coding.

Comment: Your setter for `PlayerLevel` is trying to set the `playerName` variable. You have no reason not to be using auto-properties here, regardless. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your mistake

```
public int PlayerLevel{
    get{return playerLevel;}
    set{playerName = value;}
}
```

You're trying to assign an integer to `playerName` in the setter, but `playerName` is a string, so you got the error. It should be changed to below

```
public int PlayerLevel{
    get{ return playerLevel; }
    set{ playerLevel = value; }
}
```

Assuming `BasePlayer` class only contains simple properties, you can also simplify your code as below using auto-implemented properties

```
public class BasePlayer 
{
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public int PlayerLevel { get; set; }
    public BaseCharacterClass PlayerClass { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public int Endurance { get; set; }
    public int Strength { get; set; }
    public int Health { get; set; }
}
```